# Is there an *up to date* Facebook login example or documentation?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

My question is - is there any example documentation or example project showing how to do authentication with Facebook that is up to date for iOS7?

Because trying to go through bad documentation is hard enough, but when the documentation is out of step with the source code, when both use deprecated iOS methods, or show evidence of bugs being present, or say to use nonexistent methods then its just beyond frustrating.

In particular:

1. The documentation says on the app becoming active to call `[FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive]`. But no such method exists. 
   So looking at what the scrumptious sample code does, it does nothing, instead it talks about a bug they have in their code. `BUG: for the iOS 6 preview we comment this line out to compensate for a race-condition in our state transition handling`
   So should an app do anything on the app becoming active and if so what?
2. The documentation and sample implement `application:openURL:sourceApplication:sourceApplication` however its deprecated. Therefore is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused by this question.

1. handleDidBecomeActive is a method in FBSession, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSession/
2. application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation has NOT been deprecated for UIApplicationDelegate (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:). Perhaps you were thinking about application:handleOpenURL:?

What version of the sdk are you using? The ones >= 3.8 have been updated for iOS 7.